# Diamond Operator Using Custom ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, generics, kotlin

I see the example that used ArrayAdapter. but I don't Understand a little part of the code. First Parameters is Context, Second Parameter is Xml layout File(Used its style and ... for showing our data) and the third Parameter is about our Data that be Parsed and it is a list array type.
and this function Inherits from ArrayAdapter.

ArrayAdapter Class needs at least two Parameters. Context and Resource.
But what is  in front of ArrayAdapter? and What is that mean ?

```
class FeedAdapter(context: Context, private val resource: Int, private val applications: List<FeedEntry>)
    : ArrayAdapter<FeedEntry>(context, resource)
```

Complete Code

```
class FeedAdapter(context: Context, private val resource: Int, private val applications: List<FeedEntry>)
    : ArrayAdapter<FeedEntry>(context, resource) {

    private val TAG = "FeedAdapter"
    private val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        Log.d(TAG, "getCount() called")
        return applications.size
    }

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {

        Log.d(TAG, "getView() called")
        val view = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false)

        val tvName: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.tvName)
        val tvArtist: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.tvArtist)
        val tvSummary: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.tvSummary)

        val currentApp = applications[position]

        tvName.text = currentApp.name
        tvArtist.text = currentApp.artist
        tvSummary.text = currentApp.summary

        return view
    }
}

class FeedEntry
{
    var name:String=""
    var artist :String=""
    var releaseDate:String=""
    var summary:String=""
    var imageURL:String=""

    fun feel(Name:String,Artist:String,ReleaseData:String,Summary:String,ImageURL:String)
    {
        name=Name
        artist=Artist
        releaseDate=ReleaseData
        summary=Summary
        imageURL=ImageURL
    }
    override fun toString(): String {
        return """
            name = $name
            releaseData=$releaseDate
            summary=$summary
            imageURL=$imageURL
        """.trimIndent()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your specific example, `ArrayAdapter<FeedEntry>` is an ArrayAdapter that adapts a list of objects of type FeedEntry to the RecyclerView. So the third constructor parameter `val applications: List<FeedEntry>` is the data you want it to adapt, a list of FeedEntry objects. A `List` is like an Array, but you can't modify it (unless it is a MutableList). You can pass a MutableList to this constructor, and from within this class it will be read-only.

The use of generics in this class helps you avoid having to cast instances. When you override `onBindView`, it will know you are dealing with FeedEntry instances so you won't have to cast generic `Any`s into `FeedEntry`s.

In the general sense, you should read up on Kotlin generics in the Kotlin documentation. However, I find that the Kotlin documentation seems to assume you know Java in places, so you might want to skim through the Java documentation on generics as well.

Answer (score 2):

this is Generics in java (Read this [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_generics.html) for a brief introduction ). Generic is used here so `ArrayAdapter` can show a list of any kind of objects we may use in our application. For simplification think of it as water that can shape according to any jar you put that in.